# INSERT INTO statement not working error 3134

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Currently trying to get my add button to work.  I'm trying to insert into a table and I'm getting a Run-Time error '3134.  I've watched several youtube videos and searched here.  Not sure why its erroring out.  There are no prime keys associated with this table.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblMemberRecords (strLastName, strTimeType, strCrewPosition, strStartTime, strStopTime, ) " & _
    " VALUES ('" & Me.cboLastName & "','" & Me.cboTimeType & "','" & Me.strCrewPosition & "','" & Me.strStartTime & "','" & Me.strStopTime & "')"
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with constant values.

Comment: Just starting out and will expand my knowledge base, just trying to get the thing to work at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma

```
 ... strStartTime, strStopTime, ) ...
                              ^---------------here
```

and please look up on how to use prepared statements. Don't patch your queries together like this.

Comment: And that fixed it. Thank you so much.  And now time to learn about prepared statements.